# Tabelas Exibidas no Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Boa Noite, possou instalados no meu notebook o oracle database e o oracle sql developer,ambos funcionam normalmente,mas quando conecto no SQL Developer e clico na exibiçao das tabelas ele me mostra alem das tabelas que eu mesma criei diversas outras,que todas possuem no nome o simbolo: $!

Gostaria de saber como faço para exibir apenas as tabelas que criei ou crio,e não exibir essas outras,ja que ela deixam o "menu" muito pesado de se vizualizar! E também queria saber o que seriam essas tabelas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Botão direito em tabelas -> aplicar filtro -> selecione o filtro que quer

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda,descobrir que na verdade estava exibindo todas as tabelas pq eu estava usando o login do System! Ou seja o filtro nesse caso não ajudou muito,pois teria que fazer vários

Answer (score -1):

Creio que esteja utilizando o usuário Root, por isso está vendo todas tabelas existentes, como solução basta criar um usuário para você que não seja o root e atribuir as permissões que necessita.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).